# Sprite kit ball bounce physics objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-physics, skphysicsbody

I want to add gravity to ball, so it will bounce up and down, and slightly to right or left in which angle ball bounces to, and i don't want to lose ball energy, so it bounce always in same height. For now ball bounce in every direction and stops after few min even if i set friction on 0. Here little bit of my code :

```
    ball.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/4 +arc4random() % ((int)self.frame.size.width/2),
                                self.frame.size.height/2 +arc4random() % ((int)self.frame.size.height/2));
    [self addChild:ball];

    ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:ball.frame.size.width/3];
    ball.physicsBody.friction = 0.0f;
    ball.physicsBody.restitution = 1.0f;
    ball.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.0f;
    ball.physicsBody.allowsRotation = YES;
    [ball.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(50.0f, -50.0f)];
```

Comment: it depends on your impulse, right now u r apllying impule in a croos direction.So you ar ehitting the ball in cross direction

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want the ball to bounce in every direction, then you should hit the ball in a straight direction.

If you want to maintain constant speed throught out the game, then you need to make sure you maintain the speed:

```
  if(myNode.physicsBody.velocity.dx < 30)
myNode.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(30, myNode.physicsBody.velocity.dy);
```

This applies velocity 30 , when your node velocity is less than 30

You can use this method:

```
-(void)addBallOfType:(NSString *)imageName ofSize:(CGSize) size addSpriteName:(NSString *)name atPoint:(CGPoint)point withBounce:(BOOL) bounce withVelocity:(CGVector)velocity andHitCategory:(int) category addEmitter:(BOOL) addEmitter{


    SKSpriteNode * ball = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:imageName];
    ball.name=name;
    ball.size=size;
    ball.anchorPoint=CGPointMake(0, 0);

    ball.physicsBody=[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:ball.frame.size.width/2];
    ball.physicsBody.categoryBitMask=category;
    ball.physicsBody.collisionBitMask=youCollisionBitMask;
    ball.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask= youCollisionBitMask;

    ball.physicsBody.dynamic=YES;
    ball.physicsBody.affectedByGravity=NO;
    ball.physicsBody.restitution=1.0;
    ball.physicsBody.friction=0.0;
    ball.physicsBody.linearDamping=0.0;
    ball.physicsBody.angularDamping=0.0;

    ball.position=point;
    [self addChild:ball];

     if (addEmitter) {
       _emitterNodePath =
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"RParticle" ofType:@"sks"];
       SKEmitterNode *burstEmitter =
    [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:_emitterNodePath];
    [ball addChild:burstEmitter];
    }



    if (bounce) {
        CGVector impulse = velocity;
        [ball.physicsBody applyImpulse:impulse];

    }


}
```

For hitting in different directions:

```
-(CGVector)hitToLeftWithSpeed:(float)speed{

    return CGVectorMake(-speed, 0);
}

-(CGVector)hitToRightWithSpeed:(float)speed{

    return CGVectorMake(speed, 0);
}

-(CGVector)hitTotopWithSpeed:(float)speed{

    return CGVectorMake(0, speed);
}

-(CGVector)hitToBottomWithSpeed:(float)speed{

    return CGVectorMake(0, -speed);
}

-(CGVector)forwardCrossHitWithSpeed:(float)speed{

    return CGVectorMake(speed, speed);
}

-(CGVector)backwardCrossHitWithSpeed:(float)speed{

    return CGVectorMake(-speed, -speed);
}
```

For positioning the ball:

```
  -(CGPoint)addBallAtCenterWithOffsetX:(int)x withOffsetY:(int)y{

    return CGPointMake(100+x, 100+y);
}
-(CGPoint)addBallAtTopLeftWithOffsetX:(int) x withOffsetY:(int)y{

    return CGPointMake(200+x, 100+y);
}

-(CGPoint)addBallAtTopRightWithOffsetX:(int)x withOffsetY:(int)y{

    return CGPointMake(100+x, 100+y);
}

-(CGPoint)addBallAtBottomRightWithOffsetX:(int)x withOffsetY:(int)y{

    return CGPointMake(100+x, 2100+y);
}

-(CGPoint)addBallAtBottomLeftWithOffsetX:(int)x withOffsetY:(int)y{

    return CGPointMake(100+x, 200+y);
}
```

and you can call it by:

```
 [self addBallOfType:hBlueBall ofSize:CGSizeMake(75, 75) addSpriteName:@"greenball" atPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100) withBounce:YES withVelocity:[self hitTotopWithSpeed:50] andHitCategory:blueBallHitCategory addEmitter:YES];
```

Comment: is there any easier way? i mean, i dont understand half of this code

Comment: You dont need to copy paste all these code. I posted helper methods, so that you can refer those methods.

Comment: Which part you didn't understand? I will try to explain in detail

Comment: I don't understand bitmask thing, i read about it, but don't get it

Comment: bit mask is to detect collision between nodes. If your game contains ball,wall,bat, then each has a different bit mask. You can neglect it for now.

Comment: theoretically, code can also work without bitmask, but then everything have same collision? @Mr.T

Comment: you need to have different collision mask for different object. All balls can have same collision mask, and bat must have different collision mask

Comment: i added bitmask to my code, it works, but i don't feel any difference, but its ok, its secondary thing for now, primarily is balls physics but tnx.